# Given $\mathbb{E}[X]$, $\mathbb{E}[\max(0,X)]$, and $\mathbb{E}[\min(0,X)]$, what is $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

Let $X$ be any random variable with any distribution. Given that we know $\mathbb{E}[X]$, $\mathbb{E}[\max(0,X)]$, and $\mathbb{E}[\min(0,X)]$, can you write a formula for $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]$ where $f$ is any twice differentiable function?

I've been stuck on this question for quite a while. I've tried taylor expanding $f(X)$ but I didn't know how to proceed further. This question might have something to do with the arbitrage free pricing of $f(X)$ given price of $X$, price of call option on $X$, and price of put option on $X$, though I don't know much about finance so this doesn't help me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I have no idea about how to answer the question, but here is a helpful tip about formatting: You can use `\max` and `\min` in your dollar signs to make the words appear without italics - however, if you want to preserve the italics, just keep it that way.

Comment: thanks. i edited it to \max and \min

Comment: When formulated properly this question does in fact have a lot to do with arbitrage free pricing of $f(X)$. See this [QSE post](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/67816/58786).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for a formula for $E(f(X))$ only using $EX, EX^+ = E\max(X, 0)$ and $ EX^-=E\min(X,0)$.

This cannot be possible, take for example $X = \text{unif}(0,1)$ to be the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$ and $Y= \delta_{0.5}$ to be the dirac measure in 0.5. In this case you will find that $E X = EY$, $EX^+ = EY^+$ and $EX^- = EY^-$ but $Ef(X) \neq Ef(Y)$ for some function f. (I did not do the calculations but I imagine f(x) = x^2 would work )

Comment: $f(x)=x^2$ works, as $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\int_0^1 x^2 dx = \frac{1}{3}$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y^2]=(0.5)^2=\frac{1}{4}$.